# Parallely consume records in kafka with single consumer instance

Tags: apache-kafka, queue

I have one kafka topic with 3 partition and one consumer group with one consumer instance.
Now I want that single instance to parallely consume records from each partition. So 3 records concurently from 3 partitions.
Can I achieve that with kafka?
or should I use something else?

I was expecting that they will be consumed concurrently instead of consuming one partition at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a wrapper framework like [Spring Kafka you can use](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/message-listener-container.html) a `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` to achieve that easily. Otherwise, you will need to create multiple threads but be aware that the consumer is not thread-safe so you need to make sure to instantiate one consumer per thread and execute each in its thread.

If you are using [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/36/documentation/streams/developer-guide/) you can configure the `num.stream.threads` as described [in the documentation here](https://kafka.apache.org/36/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#num-stream-threads) to achieve the same.

Comment: I am working with node JS and Kafka, I don't think it's possible there unless I use worker threads. right?

Comment: Yes, with NodeJS I don't think it's possible(NodeJS event loop) unless you use worker threads to instantiate multiple consumers running in parallel and put all of them in the same consumer group but I don't have much experience using Kafka with NodeJS although it's used where I work for simple use cases we mainly use JVM clients with Kotlin which I recommend you to try if you want to have full proper and reliable support while using Kafka. Kotlin is a very modern and pleasant language to work with.